# Where Can I Find Remote-Devices Option for Chrome Debugger?

Tags: android, google-chrome, debugging, remote-debugging, developer-tools

I'm trying to debug a website on my android phone and I want to do that by connecting to my desktop's chrome debugging tools. As far as I can find, the way to do that is to open Chrome Developer Tools, go to More Tools, and then click "Remote Devices." However, when I do that, there is nothing called "Remote Devices" present or anywhere close. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Have you followed the troubleshooting tips at: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/ Also be aware that Android Studio's `adb server` may interfere with Chrome's `adb` connection.

Comment: This does provid helpful information or answers the question by OP where to find the "Remote Devices" Tab.